# Bind data into multicolum datagrid-combobox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datagrid

I found [this tutorial](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17365.multicolumn-combobox-in-wpf-datagrid.aspx) online which is exactly what I am trying to do, but the tutorial does not explain how to load data from code behind into the combobox. any idea how I can acheive this?

Basically I want a multicolumn combobox in a datagrid, and when the user selects an item, it displays only one of the values and not both.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DGOrders" Margin="30" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OrderID}" Header="Order ID" />
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="User" Width="200">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding UserID}" SelectedValuePath="UserID" DisplayMemberPath="CompanyName" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding UserID}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CompanyName}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding UserName}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about what you meant by displaying only one of the values and not both, but i hope that explain it self once i show you how to properly bind the properties in the `DataGrid`, first of all you need to make sure that your model looks something like this :

```
public class Order
{
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public string SelectedUserId { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

then in the code behind create two collectionw to hold the users list and the orders list which represent the `DataContext` for the `ComboBox` and the `DataGrid`:

```
  private ObservableCollection<Order> _ordersCollection = new ObservableCollection<Order>()
    {
        new Order()
        {
            OrderId = "1",
            SelectedUserId = "2"
        } ,new Order()
        {
            OrderId = "2",
            SelectedUserId = "3"
        }
    };

    public ObservableCollection<Order> OrdersCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _ordersCollection;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_ordersCollection == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _ordersCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<User> _usersCollection = new ObservableCollection<User>()
    {
        new User()
        {
            UserId = "1",
            UserName = "Name1",
            CompanyName = "Company1"
        } ,new User()
        {
            UserId = "2",
            UserName = "Name2",
            CompanyName = "Company2"
        } ,new User()
        {
            UserId = "3",
            UserName = "Name3",
            CompanyName = "Company3"
        }
    };


    public ObservableCollection<User> UsersCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _usersCollection;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_usersCollection == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _usersCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

you may consider implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface so that the UI will be notified each time the collection is updated.

Now in the UI, make sure your main window's `DataContext` is set to the codebehind using this

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

then properly bind the Properties:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DGOrders" Margin="30" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding OrdersCollection}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OrderId}" Header="Order ID" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="User" Width="200" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedUserId}" SelectedValuePath="UserId" DisplayMemberPath="CompanyName" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.UsersCollection,ElementName=DGOrders}" >
                            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding UserId}"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CompanyName}"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding UserName}"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

you will end up with something like this

[image]

Comment: thanks for your time and answer. I tried what you suggested and get the following error - Error 1 No overload for method 'OnPropertyChanged' takes 0 argument'

Comment: In the codebehind implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface

Comment: Thanks that worked. Out of curiosity, would this method work if the datacontext was a from a dataset?